# Capture tee's argument inside piped Perl execution

Tags: perl, unix

How to capture piped command's argument ?

I use :

```
perl my_script.pl -some_args  |  tee arg_filename
```

How to get `arg_filename` 's value inside `my_script.pl` ?

**CONTEXT**
I need to send this filename in a mail which `my_script.pl` sends at the end.
I need to use `tee` because we dump huge output in the standard logging which we use inside `my_script.pl` but we `print` more relevant things on `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.
This script imports and uses additional proprietary libraries which could not be edited. But they too generate logs.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain why you need to access the tee'd filename in your Perl script?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Added context. Please me know if you need more information.

Comment: It's still an xy problem - you can't do this the way you're trying to do it.

Comment: @Sobrique Do yo mean this is not possible in Unix ? I had a feeling that there should be a way.

Comment: Processes don't get to interfere with other processes. You could probably run a `ps` and grep the arguments out, but this is an icky nasty thing to do and is unlikely to be at the heart of the problem you're trying to solve. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is - you can't.

`tee` is a separate process with it's own arguments. There is no way to access these arguments from that process. (well, I suppose you could run `ps` or something).

The point of `tee` is to take `STDOUT` write some of it to a log file, and pass through the rest of it down the 'pipe'. (Which results in printing it if nothing else).

What you could probably do instead is implement some manner of logging within your perl script, where the core functionality of `tee` is replicated by printing a line to both `STDOUT` and a designated log file.

Comment: Ok. I would try overriding the logging function by a subroutine which writes to a file and then calls the original overridden logging function. That way it could be handled from inside my perl script.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to "cheat", I might try something akin to:

```
#!/bin/sh
MYLOG=/tmp/logfile
export MYLOG
perl my_script.pl -some_args  |  tee $MYLOG
```

That is, get the name of the `tee` file before you invoke either `perl` or `tee`.  Everyone else's answers are more correct;  I only mention this as a counter-measure.